# DataGrid Column Sets with a header for each set

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I wanted to create a WPF data grid which displays a certian number of column sets for each category as in the below image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7ZED.png)

Can anyone help me how we can achieve this with wpf Datagrid?

Comment: I suppose the main/upper columns are not constant? cuz then you could just add a grid with 3(?) columns on top of the data grid

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `DataGrid` in a `Grid` panel and then bind its `ColumnDefinitions` widths to the column headers widths. Something like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=datagrid, Path=RowHeaderWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColumnD, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColumnE, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColumnF, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColumnG, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColumnH, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColumnI, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGridColumnHeader Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="A" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <DataGridColumnHeader Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="B" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <DataGridColumnHeader Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="C" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Grid.Row="1" RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="D" Width="*" x:Name="ColumnD" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="E" Width="*" x:Name="ColumnE" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="F" Width="*" x:Name="ColumnF" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="G" Width="*" x:Name="ColumnG" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="H" Width="*" x:Name="ColumnH" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="I" Width="*" x:Name="ColumnI" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

My XAML does not consider header's borders, but you can easily include them by using a converter which gets the `ActualWidth` and sum it to the border thickness.

I hope it can help you.